# Filter in angular ng-init

Tags: angularjs

I try to initialise a collection in the `ng-init`. Why this code does not work?

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
  <ul ng-init="myPeople=(people|filter:{show:true})" ng-repeat="person in myPeople">
    <li>{{person.name}}, {{person.show}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/serhio/pen/NrRBxe?editors=1010)

I don't need using `ng-if` or other things, I just wonder if possible to initialise a collection using a filter in **`ng-init`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-init` would not work when data is coming asynchronously, and I don't think so `ng-init` suits your case.

I'd suggest you to use alias for filtered data in `ng-repeat` itself, while filtering `myPeople` collection

```
ng-repeat="person in people|filter:{show:true} as myPeople"
```

Comment: just... is it possible to use it in the ng-init? I want to hide the parent element of ng-repeat if no elements in the filter, like this: http://codepen.io/serhio/pen/aZmjGW?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can initialize filter in `ng-init` like

```
ng-init="FilteredGeojson = (ho | filter:search)"
```

Regards.

Comment: like I do in the OP?

Answer (score 0):

Because you write your `ng-init` on element, that repeated you `ng-init` code run every time for new tag. To avoid this write `ng-init` somewhere else.

Like this

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('PeopleCtrl', function($scope, $window) {


  $scope.people = ([{
    id: 17,
    name: "Peter",
    age: 21,
    show: true
  }, {
    id: 07,
    name: "David",
    age: 20,
    show: false
  }, {
    id: 37,
    name: "Anil",
    age: 22,
    show: true
  }, {
    id: 45,
    name: "Anil",
    age: 19,
    show: false
  }]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PeopleCtrl" ng-init="myPeople=(people|filter:{show:true})">
  <ul ng-repeat="person in myPeople">
    <li>{{person.name}}, {{person.show}}
  </ul>
</div>
```